# No communication between SignalR nodes when using Redis on Windows - how to resolve?

Tags: redis, load-balancing, signalr-hub

I will be setting up a scale-out with fail-over environment using SignalR and Redis.  The first step is to ensure that Redis is handling communication between SignalR nodes (the current issue).  This will be followed by wiring up Redis Sentinel, and BookSleeve for the SignalR nodes to access a single Redis endpoint.

In his article [Scaling SignalR with Redis](http://blog.mirajavora.com/scaling-signalr-with-redishttp://blog.mirajavora.com/scaling-signalr-with-redis.),  @mirajavora explains how to setup a single instance Redis environment.

For testing (even though this will eventually reside on a *nix box), I setup Redis on Windows.  The server boots up and I configured the SignalR application to use the Redis message bus.

I verified that the SignalR application is using Redis, by running the app without Redis running.  I get an expected error indicating:

> No connection could be made because the target machine actively
>   refused it 127.0.0.1:6379

I then launch Redis and recycle the SignalR app pool.

Using the following URL, I verified that the SignalR app is communicating with Redis:

> newsfeedlocal1:8082/signalr?transport=longPolling&connectionId=7285d6e5-412c-4bca-9897-5f9ab1ebcece&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22newsfeedhub%22%7D%5D&messageId=B%2C0%7CF%2C2%7CG%2C0%7CH%2C0&tid=5&callback=jQuery17204961678246036172_1357588747275&_=1357588762433

Redis status:

[image: Redis accepted connection]

So far so good... application runs as expected.

Near the end of his article, Mira has the following line in Global.asax, which I don't see in the other documentation:

> RouteTable.Routes.MapConnection("echo",
>   "echo/{*operation}");

I don't have a DistributedConnection object in my SignalR project, and have left this out (as I did not see it in the [GitHub Documentation](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/SignalR-with-Redis-Running-on-a-Windows-Azure-Virtual-Machine). Any further explanation of this line?

Mira's article suggests increasing Maximum Number Of Worker Processes to test locally.  Setting this to any number other than 1, breaks the communication between nodes.  Client 1 performs some action that will notify connected client 2 - where window 1 sends a notification to client 2 on window 2.

I do see multiple worker processes, but somehow I don't think this is a good test scenario. I have Fiddler open, but not sure what to look for to further debug this issue.  Also does testing like this really simulate multiple SignalR nodes properly?

Currently I'm testing this without a load-balancer.  Are there any recommended software load-balancers?